# How to access your AWS Redis cache instance using Java code?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-ec2, redis

I want to use AWS Redis cache for my application package. I have created an Ec2 instance through which I am able to access my cache instance by SSH through console. But I want to access it through Java code. It would be helpful if anyone could direct me to some codebase where it's already in use.
I read in its AWS documentation that you could only access it through an EC2 instance. For that I was using SSH tunnels to link my EC2 instance with the cache endpoints. I wanted to know is there an alternate way to do this without creating tunnels.

Comment: What do u mean by java code? Do u want to access it from server side or client side?

Comment: I have a package which runs on server side and hits Database to fetch values. I want to add a cache in between my host server and the database.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use any of the redis-java drivers in your app. Create a redis-cache connection from your existing application and store/update/read value while you are saving/updating/reading from mysql DB. Redis java drivers could be found in [Redis Clients](https://redis.io/clients#java).

Example code:

- [Redis - Java](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_java.htm)
- [Intro to Jedis – the Java Redis Client Library](http://www.baeldung.com/jedis-java-redis-client-library)

Comment: Also, edit the security groups to allow redis port access.